# How to add function on button in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js, tween.js

There is already a written program in Three JS. I'd like to add animated function on button click event.
And how to set buttons in inner window. I want to call all animations on button click event.  Please help Thanks.

[The same code is in this link of three js](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_skinning_morph)

Code is here

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Skinning and morphing</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <style>
   body {
    color: #222545;
   }

   a {
    color: #2fa1d6;
   }

   p {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0 2em;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 

 <body>
  
 <div class="btn-group">
 <button id="walking" class="button" onclick="">Standing</button>
 <button id="Idle" class="button" onclick="">Idle</button>
 <button id="Standing" class="button" onclick="" >Walking</button>
 <button id="Death" class="button" onclick="" >Death</button>
 </div>
 

  <script type="module">
  

   import * as THREE from './js/three.module.js';

   import Stats from './js/stats.module.js';
   import { GUI } from './js/dat.gui.module.js';

   import { GLTFLoader } from './js/GLTFLoader.js';

   var container, stats, clock, gui, mixer, actions, activeAction, previousAction;
   var camera, scene, renderer, model, face;

   var api = { state: 'Death' };

   init();
   animate();

   function init() {

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.25, 100 );
    camera.position.set( - 5, 3, 10 );
    camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 2, 0 ) );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xe0e0e0 );
    scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xe0e0e0, 20, 100 );

    clock = new THREE.Clock();

    // lights

    var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0x444444 );
    light.position.set( 0, 20, 0 );
    scene.add( light );

    light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
    light.position.set( 0, 20, 10 );
    scene.add( light );

    // ground

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2000, 2000 ), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x999999, depthWrite: false } ) );
    mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
    scene.add( mesh );

    var grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 200, 40, 0x000000, 0x000000 );
    grid.material.opacity = 0.2;
    grid.material.transparent = true;
    scene.add( grid );

    // model

    var loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load( 'models/RobotExpressive.glb', function ( gltf ) {

     model = gltf.scene;
     scene.add( model );

     createGUI( model, gltf.animations );

    }, undefined, function ( e ) {

     console.error( e );

    } );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    // stats
    stats = new Stats();
    container.appendChild( stats.dom );

   }

   function createGUI( model, animations ) {

    var states = [ 'Idle', 'Walking', 'Running', 'Dance', 'Death', 'Sitting', 'Standing' ];
    var emotes = [ 'Jump', 'Yes', 'No', 'Wave', 'Punch', 'ThumbsUp' ];

    gui = new GUI();

    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( model );

    actions = {};

    for ( var i = 0; i < animations.length; i ++ ) {

     var clip = animations[ i ];
     var action = mixer.clipAction( clip );
     actions[ clip.name ] = action;

     if ( emotes.indexOf( clip.name ) >= 0 || states.indexOf( clip.name ) >= 4 ) {

      action.clampWhenFinished = true;
      action.loop = THREE.LoopOnce;

     }

    }

    // states

    var statesFolder = gui.addFolder( 'States' );

    var clipCtrl = statesFolder.add( api, 'state' ).options( states );

    clipCtrl.onChange( function () {

     fadeToAction( api.state, 0.5 );

    } );

    statesFolder.open();

    // emotes

    var emoteFolder = gui.addFolder( 'Emotes' );

    function createEmoteCallback( name ) {

     api[ name ] = function () {

      fadeToAction( name, 0.2 );

      mixer.addEventListener( 'finished', restoreState );

     };

     emoteFolder.add( api, name );

    }

    function restoreState() {

     mixer.removeEventListener( 'finished', restoreState );

     fadeToAction( api.state, 0.2 );

    }

    for ( var i = 0; i < emotes.length; i ++ ) {

     createEmoteCallback( emotes[ i ] );

    }

    emoteFolder.open();

    // expressions

    face = model.getObjectByName( 'Head_2' );

    var expressions = Object.keys( face.morphTargetDictionary );
    var expressionFolder = gui.addFolder( 'Expressions' );

    for ( var i = 0; i < expressions.length; i ++ ) {

     expressionFolder.add( face.morphTargetInfluences, i, 0, 1, 0.01 ).name( expressions[ i ] );

    }

    activeAction = actions[ 'Death' ];
    activeAction.play();

    expressionFolder.open();

   }

   function fadeToAction( name, duration ) {  //want to add this animated function on click event
   

    previousAction = activeAction;
    activeAction = actions[ name ];

    if ( previousAction !== activeAction ) {

     previousAction.fadeOut( duration );

    }

    activeAction
     .reset()
     .setEffectiveTimeScale( 1 )
     .setEffectiveWeight( 1 )
     .fadeIn( duration )
     .play();

   }
   document.getElementById("Death").addEventListener("click", fadeToAction('Death',0.5));


   function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

   }

   //

   function animate() {

    var dt = clock.getDelta();

    if ( mixer ) mixer.update( dt );

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

    stats.update();

   }

  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

please help me how to do this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Three.js is using [dat.gui](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui) for it's gui.

A simple button that would run a function whenever it is pressed would be something like.

```
function buttonFunction() {
    //do button 
    //stuff here.
}

var params = {
    ClickMe: buttonFunction
};

var gui = new GUI();
var folder = gui.addFolder('My folder');

folder.add(params, 'ClickMe');

folder.open();
```

Comment: Please tell me how to call function fadetoaction () on button with para meters. I tried to call the function but nothing changes.